# Set pair intersection

Tags: c++, algorithm

This is my first post so bear with me.
I always wandered if there is a more optimal way to check all the pairs in an array of size n, other than O(n^2). 
Aside from the usual idea of :

```
       for(i : n)
          for(j : n)
             process(a[i], a[j]);
```

I was wandering if a hash table could do the trick...

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Depends on `process`. What do you want to exactly? If you want set intersection, sort the two ranges first (O(n log n) or better), then use [std::set_intersection](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection) (O(n)).

Comment: What does `process` do?

Comment: -1 Unclear what's asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the code

```
   for(i : n)
      for(j : n)
         process(a[i], a[j]);
```

where `process` might be to output the pair (it's unspecified what `process` does), you're wondering if this can be done in some more efficient way.

No, not in general, for in order to output each pair, you need to process each pair.

However, if `process` is the operation "do nothing", then this can be done very much more efficiently than actually looping, and don't be surprised if your compiler figures that out.

In between "output" and "do nothing" there's a range of possible behaviors. For example, perhaps `process` notes whether all values are the same? In that case a single scan through the array can do the job.

---

In passing, note that `n` is an unusual short name for an array. Instead it's common to use the letter `a`. The letter `n` more signifies a count.

Answer (score 0):

The `O(N²)` behavior directly derives from the number of pairs, `N²`. If you need to process all pairs, whatever the order and whatever the storage strategy, the complexity will beat least `O(N²)`. This is called the trivial bound as it is obvious from the problem statement.

The double loop achieving this bound, there is no benefit trying more sophisticated approaches.

The only shortcut is when the pairs are symmetric and need be handled only once:

```
for (i : 0 to N-2):
    for (j : i + 1 to N-1)
        Process(a[i], a[j]);
```

(omit the `+ 1` in case `a[i], a[i]` pairs must be processed too).